# Select specific text from website page

Tags: c#, web

I get a webpage content using this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var pageContent = client.DownloadString("http://www.modern-railways.com");
        Console.WriteLine(pageContent);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This is what I get:

```
…….News: <span class='articleTitle'>Victoria Metrolink improvement begins</span></a></h1><p><a href='/view_article.asp?ID=7541&pubID=37&t=0&s=0&sO=both&p=1&i=10' class='summaryText' data-ajax='false'>Published 13 February 2014, 11:28</a></p><div class='articleContent ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all '….
```

I need to capture all the "articleTitle" and the published date in the pageContent in which there are several of them. How can I do that? I need some direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to accomplish your challenge:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"<span class='articleTitle'>(.+?)</span>");

var match = regex.Match(pageContent);

var result = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

The above code will work assuming that the  tag is built in the exactly same way every time.

```
foreach (Match itemMatch in regex.Matches(pageContent))
{
    var articleTitle= itemMatch.Groups[1].Value;
    //TODO do what you need with the articleTitle (e.g. add to a list)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It i s working but it shows only the first title in the page and I have to cach all of them.